# React createPortal doesn't insert the child in a container

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a very simple to do list app on react the app should basically mount one li inside a ul every time I click a button using a function everything seems to work normal except createProtal method doesn't trigger the new UI to render , code to reproduce the same problem:

```
import React  from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends React.Component {
   add(){
    var textInput=document.getElementById("textInput").value;
    ReactDOM.createPortal(<li>{textInput}</li> ,document.getElementById('ul'));
   }
render(){
 return (
  <div>
    To Do list:
    <ul id='ul'></ul>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" />
    <input type="Button" value="Add" onClick={this.add}/>
  </div>
  );
}
}

export default App
```

Comment: are u testing createPortal or trying to achieve the code goal?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the code goal by mounting list item inside an unordered list I wanted to know why create protal didn't work and how to fix the problem

Comment: is the answer I added what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the createPortal in your code didn't work because it needs to be inside the render method

this code shows how createPortal works and how to achieve your goal in the reactjs  standard way, let me know if u have any questions

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        todos: [],
        textInput: '',
    };

    addNewTodo = () => {
        this.setState({
            todos: [
                ...this.state.todos,
                { id: Math.random(), value: this.state.textInput },
            ],
        });
    };

    handleChange = (e) =>
        this.setState({
            textInput: e.target.value,
        });

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.todos.length !== 0 &&
                    ReactDOM.createPortal(
                        <ul id='ul'>
                            {this.state.todos.map((todo) => (
                                <li key={todo.id}>{todo.value}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>,
                        document.getElementById('notWhereTheListOriginallyAt')
                    )}
                <div id='notWhereTheListOriginallyAt'></div>
                To Do list:
                <input
                    type='text'
                    id='textInput'
                    value={this.state.textInput}
                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                />
                <button type='Button' onClick={this.addNewTodo}>
                    Add
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```